# Android/Java BluetoothSocket InputStream won't read data

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I am implementing a simple app that sends and receives data between two devices via bluetooth. 
I am following the android developer's blog's bluetoothchat example, but my application seems unable to read from the inputstream of a socket.

Writing to the socket is fine. The app does not throw an error nor update the textview as it is supposed to. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Main activity.java(where list of devices are shown and selected) - probably not the errored file:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 22;
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    private static final String NAME = "Bluetooth!";
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> deviceList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ScanReciever reciever;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetooth_adapter;
    Button onButton;
    Button scanButton;
    Button alreadyButton;
    AcceptThread acceptThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
        //arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.xml.table_item, android.R.id.text1, deviceList);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.table_item);

        // Set up Buttons
        onButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onButton);
        scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
        onButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                askAdapterOn();
            }
        });
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scanForDevices();
            }
        });

        // Set up listview
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
                callButtons(deviceList.get(position));
            }
        });

        // Bluetooth setup.
        bluetooth_adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        // If device is incapable of using bluetooth:
        if (bluetooth_adapter == null) {
            onButton.setEnabled(false);
            scanButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (!bluetooth_adapter.isEnabled()) { // If bluetooth is off:
            //Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            //startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            onButton.setEnabled(true);
            scanButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else { // Bluetooth is on and ready:
            onButton.setEnabled(false);
            scanButton.setEnabled(true);


            alreadyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alreadyButton);
            alreadyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Collect current devices into a set.
                    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetooth_adapter.getBondedDevices();
                    // Pass the index of the paired device
                    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                        callButtons(pairedDevices.iterator().next()); // First element in set.
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No paired Device!");
                    }
                }
            });

            acceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            acceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    private class ScanReciever extends BroadcastReceiver  {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                System.out.println("Started");
                //discovery starts, we can show progress dialog or perform other tasks
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                System.out.println("finished");
                //discovery finishes, dismis progress dialog
            } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                //bluetooth device found
                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                System.out.println("FOUND: " + device.getName());
                deviceList.add(device);
                arrayAdapter.add(device.getName()+" - Click to pair");
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                System.out.println("Connected~!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                callButtons(deviceList.get(deviceList.size()-1));
            }

        }
    };

    protected void askAdapterOn() {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    protected void scanForDevices() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

        reciever = new ScanReciever();
        registerReceiver(reciever, filter);
        bluetooth_adapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    protected void callButtons(BluetoothDevice bd) {
        bluetooth_adapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Intent toButton = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), buttons.class);
        toButton.putExtra("selected",bd);
        startActivity(toButton);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                if (bluetooth_adapter.isEnabled()){
                    onButton.setEnabled(false);
                    scanButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else {
                    onButton.setEnabled(true);
                    scanButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(reciever);

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
            // because mmServerSocket is final
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
                tmp = bluetooth_adapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
                System.out.println("READY TO ACCEPT");
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
            while (true) {
                try {
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                    //manageConnectedSocket(socket);
                    try {
                        mmServerSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) { }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Buttons.java(where the app will initiate a connection and maintain communication) - probably the file with the error:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.UUID;

public class buttons extends Activity {
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    BluetoothDevice selected;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    TextView tv;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button unpairB;
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    ConnectThread connectThread;
    ConnectedThread connectedThread;
    BluetoothSocket mmSocket;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buttons);
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        selected = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("selected");
        pair(selected);
        connectedThread = null;
        try {
            connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
            connectedThread.start();
            System.out.println("ConnectedThread started!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("unpair()", e.getMessage());
        }

        // Set up Buttons
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        unpairB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.unpairButton);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonPressed(1);
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonPressed(2);
            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonPressed(3);
            }
        });
        unpairB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                unpair(selected);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Set up textview
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText("connected to: " + selected.getName());
    }

    protected void buttonPressed(int i) {
        connectedThread.write(i);
        tv.setText(Integer.toString(i));
    }

    private void pair(BluetoothDevice device) {
        connectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        connectThread.start();
    }

    private void unpair(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
            m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("unpair()", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                System.out.println("Socket was created in ConnectThread");
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            // bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
            //manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
        }

        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private final OutputStream outputStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            this.bluetoothSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            System.out.println("Connected to " + socket.getRemoteDevice().getName());
            try {
                tmpIn = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            inputStream = tmpIn;
            outputStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            if (inputStream == null) System.out.println("Inputstream is null");
            else System.out.println("Inputstream is safe");
            if (outputStream == null) System.out.println("outstream is null");
            else System.out.println("Outputstream is safe");
            while (true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Blocking?");
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    System.out.println("NO");
                    handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1,
                            buffer).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        public void write(int i) {
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                buffer[0] = (byte) i;
                outputStream.write(buffer);
                outputStream.flush();
                handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1,
                        buffer).sendToTarget();
                System.out.println("Write SUCCESS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("write ERRORRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR");
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    System.out.println("Write was broadcasted");
                    byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String writeMessage = new String(Integer.toString(writeBuf[0]));
                    ///tv.setText(writeMessage);
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    System.out.println("Read was broadcasted");
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String readMessage = new String(Integer.toString(readBuf[0]));
                    tv.setText(readMessage);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```